# How to activate a specific worksheet in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba

I just need to activate a certain worksheet. I have a string variable that keeps the name of the worksheet.

Comment: Is it possible to have the top answer accepted (either by @Alex or by a mod)? I would love to see this gone from open questions just to accommodate my OCD ^^

Answer (score 100):

Would the following Macro help you?

```
Sub activateSheet(sheetname As String)
'activates sheet of specific name
    Worksheets(sheetname).Activate
End Sub
```

Basically you want to make use of the .Activate function. Or you can use the .Select function like so:

```
Sub activateSheet(sheetname As String)
'selects sheet of specific name
    Sheets(sheetname).Select
End Sub
```

Comment: `sheetname` can be worksheet index number (so integer). Even if the `Option Base` value is 0, it starts from index 1.

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend you to use worksheet's index instead of using worksheet's name, in this way you can also loop through sheets "dynamically"

```
for i=1 to thisworkbook.sheets.count
 sheets(i).activate
'You can add more code 
with activesheet
 'Code...
end with
next i
```

It will also, improve performance.

Comment: How does this improve performance over `Worksheets().Activate`?

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way to (not dynamically) link a text to activate a worksheet without macros is to make the selected string an actual link.
You can do this by selecting the cell that contains the text and press CTRL+K then select the option/tab 'Place in this document' and select the tab you want to activate.
If you would click the text (that is now a link) the configured sheet will become active/selected.